# Populating a Dictionary of functions from a database

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, tuples

I'm working on a MUD, and currently the command handler is a Tuple that takes a string readString and Player PlayerObj with a switch statement to determine the return Tuple

```
public Tuple<string, Player> handleCMD(string readString, Player PlayerObj)
{
    Tuple<string, Player> returnTuple = new Tuple<string, Player>(readString, PlayerObj);
    string[] arguments = readString.Split(' ');

    switch (arguments[0].ToLower())
    {
        case "addchange":
            returnTuple = doAddChange(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "changes":
            returnTuple = doChanges(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "score":
            returnTuple = doScore(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "look":
            returnTuple = doLook(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "north":
            returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "east":
            returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "south":
            returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "west":
            returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "quit":
            returnTuple = doQuit(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "chat":
            returnTuple = doChat(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "say":
            returnTuple = doSay(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "who":
            returnTuple = doWho(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        case "tell":
            returnTuple = doTell(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
        default:
            returnTuple = doHuh(readString, PlayerObj);
            break;
    }
    return returnTuple;
}

public Tuple<string, Player> doSay(string readString, Player PlayerObj)
{
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
    PlayerObj = dbHandler.GetPlayer(PlayerObj.PlayerName);
    string returnString;
    string[] arguments = readString.Split(' ');
    if (arguments.Count() > 1 && arguments[1] != string.Empty && arguments[1] != null && arguments[1] != "" && arguments[1] != " ")
    {
        readString = readString.Trim().Replace("say ", "");
        Message message = new Message(0, readString, PlayerObj.PlayerID, 0, 1, 1);
        returnString = string.Format("You say \"{0}\"", readString);
        foreach (int i in dbHandler.GetPlayersInRoom(PlayerObj.RoomID, PlayerObj.PlayerName))
            dbHandler.AddMessage(new Message(0, message.MessageText, message.SenderPlayerID, i, message.MessageType, message.Ticked));
    }
    else
        returnString = "[Syntax] : Say <Message>";
    return new Tuple<string, Player>(returnString, PlayerObj);
}
```

I'd like to replace the switch statement with a Dictionary populated by a table in the database so I can add and disable commands/aliases in the database table without having the edit the code

I've tried to do it like this:

```
public Tuple<string, Player> handleCMD(string readString, Player PlayerObj)
{
    Tuple<string, Player> returnTuple = new Tuple<string, Player>(readString, PlayerObj);
    string[] arguments = readString.Split(' ');
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();

    Dictionary<string, Delegate> cmdDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    foreach (Command playerCommand in dbHandler.GetCommands())
        cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(playerCommand.CommandTuple));
    if (cmdDictionary[arguments[0]] != null)
        returnTuple = (Tuple<string, Player>)cmdDictionary[arguments[0]].DynamicInvoke(readString, PlayerObj);
    else
        returnTuple = doHuh(readString, PlayerObj);
    return returnTuple;
}
```

The problem is I get the error message:

```
cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(playerCommand.CommandTuple));
'GWOService.Command.CommandTuple' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'
```

playerCommand.CommandName is a string that = "doSay" or "doHuh" or whatever the name of the tuple is, but the following works:

```
cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(doSay/*playerCommand.CommandTuple*/));
```

*Update*

So I've tried again with the following:

```
public Tuple<string, Player> handleCMD(string readString, Player PlayerObj)
{
    Tuple<string, Player> returnTuple = new Tuple<string, Player>(readString, PlayerObj);
    string[] arguments = readString.Split(' ');
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> cmdDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    foreach (Command playerCommand in dbHandler.GetCommands())
    {
        try
        {
            MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod(playerCommand.CommandTuple);
            //Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> func = ( ) => { return (Tuple<string, Player>)(this.GetType().GetMethod(playerCommand.CommandTuple).Invoke(this, new object[0])); }
            Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> func = (Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>), method);
            cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(func));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dbHandler.LogEntry(PlayerObj, e.ToString());
        }
    }
    if (cmdDictionary[arguments[0]] != null)
        returnTuple = (Tuple<string, Player>)cmdDictionary[arguments[0]].DynamicInvoke(readString, PlayerObj);
    else
        returnTuple = doHuh(readString, PlayerObj);

    //switch (arguments[0].ToLower())
    //{
    //    case "addchange":
    //        returnTuple = doAddChange(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "changes":
    //        returnTuple = doChanges(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "score":
    //        returnTuple = doScore(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "look":
    //        returnTuple = doLook(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "north":
    //        returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "east":
    //        returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "south":
    //        returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "west":
    //        returnTuple = doWalk(arguments[0], PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "quit":
    //        returnTuple = doQuit(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "chat":
    //        returnTuple = doChat(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "say":
    //        returnTuple = doSay(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "who":
    //        returnTuple = doWho(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    case "tell":
    //        returnTuple = doTell(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //    default:
    //        returnTuple = doHuh(readString, PlayerObj);
    //        break;
    //}
    return returnTuple;
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

Line 25

```
Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> func = (Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>), method);

System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method)
at GWOService.CmdHandler.handleCMD(String readString, Player PlayerObj) in \Projects\GodWarsOxide\GWOService\CmdHandler.cs:line 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetMethod` to get the method you need to call by its name

```
this.GetType().GetMethod("doSay")
```

Then you can create a `Func` or `Delegate` on the `Invoke` command of the `MethodInfo` with the required arguments and return type

```
var function = new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>((arg1, arg2) => (Tuple<string, Player>)this.GetType().GetMethod("doSay").Invoke(this, new object[] { arg1, arg2 })));
```

Wrap it up to make it reusable

```
public Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> CreateFunction(string methodName)
{
    if (this.GetType().GetMethods().Any(x => x.Name == methodName))
    {
        return new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>((arg1, arg2) => (Tuple<string, Player>)this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, new object[] { arg1, arg2 }));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can add these to your `Dictionary`

```
  var functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>>();
  functions.Add("Say",CreateFunction("doSay"));
```

or from you `Database`

```
foreach (Command playerCommand in dbHandler.GetCommands())
{
    if (!functions.ContainsKey(playerCommand.CommandName))
    {
        functions.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, CreateFunction(playerCommand.CommandTuple));
    }
}
```

And then you can call them whenever

```
 var result = functions["Say"]("Hello", new Player());
```

---

### Note:

I suggest replacing `Tuple<sting, Player>` with a nice class instead like below as it will be less painful to deal with throughout your application

```
public void Test()
{
    Dictionary<string, Func<string, Player, MyResult>> functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, Player, MyResult>>();
    functions.Add("Say",CreateFunction("doSay"));
    var result = functions["Say"]("Hello", new Player());
}

public Func<string, Player, MyResult> CreateFunction(string methodName)
{
    if (this.GetType().GetMethods().Any(x => x.Name == methodName))
    {
        return new Func<string, Player, MyResult>((arg1, arg2) => (MyResult)this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(this, new object[] { arg1, arg2 }));
    }
    return null;
}

public MyResult doSay(string value1, Player value2)
{
    return new MyResult(value1, value2);
}

public class MyResult
{
    public MyResult(string value1, Player value2)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
    }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public Player Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for **1st** error try:

```
cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(playerCommand.CommandTuple));
```

for **2nd** error try:

```
returnTuple = (System.Tuple<string,GWOService.Player>)cmdDictionary[arguments[0]].DynamicInvoke(readString, PlayerObj);
```

I think this would work, although haven't tested it

Comment: For the 1st error if I change it to .Add() I still get the same error playerCommand.CommandTuple is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: oh, ok sorry, I didn't read the error, so  `playerCommand.CommandTuple` is a property right ? If yes, you can't convert it easily to Func because it's a special type of function(s) (getter and/or setter - potentially two functions) which is internal. You can get either the getter and/or the setter via reflection but that's not something I believe you want to do.

Comment: A walkaround could be to try to store the `playerCommand` object instead of it's `CommandTuple` property and then call it on the stored object. Is this a viable option for your app ?

Comment: `cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(playerCommand.CommandTuple));`
If playerCommand.CommanTuple is "doSay" it doesn't like it because it's a property

but the following works:

`cmdDictionary.Add(playerCommand.CommandName, new Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>(doSay));`

Comment: Ok, so can you extract the actual function from the value of the property ? can you achive something like this `Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> doSay = playerCommand.CommandTuple.doSay ..` ?

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of getting rid of the switch?
playerCommand.CommandTuple is a string that = "doSay" or "doChat" or whatever the name of the Tuple is for the command name "say" or "chat" etc. Like in the switch statement "north", "east", "south", and "west" are all doWalk

Comment: Yes, it does. I see your problem now. Ok so you need another dictionary to map the string name "doSay" to the function like this `Dictionary<string, Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>>> PlayerFunctions = new ..` then populate it once only with all the functions. Then you can do `PlayersFunctions[playerCommand.CommandName]` in the problem line. There is fancy way to populate the dictionary reflection but manually adding them to the new dictionary would do just fine too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, isn't that just another hard coded alternative to the switch statement? Is there no way to invoke a function where the function name matches the value of the string?

Comment: Yes, it is but unlike the switch statement it's log(1) in time :) This is what you are trying to achive right ? Also if you don't want to hard code anything you can extract them from the `Type` using reflection

Comment: `Is there no way to invoke a function where the function name matches the value of the string` this is another alternative yes but it would be slower - much slower then the switch statement! But if you want to do that you need to use some reflection again and a helper method something like  `GetPlayerFunction(playerCommand.CommandName)` which would return Func<string, Player, Tuple<string, Player>> with the matching function. I think that eventually the Dictionary approach is what is the optimal solution

Comment: My problem with the switch statement is if I want to add something like a doCommands command then I have to manually list all the commands, or if I want change what Tuple a command name maps to then I need to recompile the solution.

So I got a database table with a column for the name of the command and a column for the name of the tuple I want to map it to for populating the dictionary of the actual command tuples.

Comment: I understand yes, so still Dictionary to map the command name to the command populated with reflection avoids re-compilation. When you add new command you have to re-populate the dictionary. I would write you the code but I really have to leave now sorry. Good luck